# How to validate a self-issued JWT?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

I was looking at the section about [Self-issued OpenID Provider Response](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SelfIssuedResponse), where they describe a method of validation, where the public key is included in the token itself. They use this as an example token:

```
{
  "iss": "https://self-issued.me",
  "sub": "NzbLsXh8uDCcd-6MNwXF4W_7noWXFZAfHkxZsRGC9Xs",
  "aud": "https://client.example.org/cb",
  "nonce": "n-0S6_WzA2Mj",
  "exp": 1311281970,
  "iat": 1311280970,
  "sub_jwk": {
    "kty":"RSA",
    "n": "0vx7agoebGcQSuuPiLJXZptN9nndrQmbXEps2aiAFbWhM78LhWx
    4cbbfAAtVT86zwu1RK7aPFFxuhDR1L6tSoc_BJECPebWKRXjBZCiFV4n3oknjhMs
    tn64tZ_2W-5JsGY4Hc5n9yBXArwl93lqt7_RN5w6Cf0h4QyQ5v-65YGjQR0_FDW2
    QvzqY368QQMicAtaSqzs8KJZgnYb9c7d0zgdAZHzu6qMQvRL5hajrn1n91CbOpbI
    SD08qNLyrdkt-bFTWhAI4vMQFh6WeZu0fM4lFd2NcRwr3XPksINHaQ-G_xBniIqb
    w0Ls1jF44-csFCur-kEgU8awapJzKnqDKgw",
    "e":"AQAB"
  }
}
```

I get how you can use the appended key for validation. But I don't get what prevents someone from using a fake key-pair to create a similar token. The only way I see this happening is if the public key is known by the validator from somewhere else, but in that case it doesn't make a lot of sense to include it in the token.

How does this work?

Answer (score 1):

The way this work is that the hackers don't have access to the private key that was used to sign the token signature. The public key is derived from the private key.

The public key is safe to distribute as it only verifies the token signature. T

I don't think it's that common to include the public key inside the token as the token size gets bigger. Instead, you, as a receiver, download it separately, or it is provided to you some other way.

The picture below gives a summary of how public-key cryptography works.

[image]

Comment: Since app won't know the private key either, what prevents an attacker from generating their own private key, deriving a public key for that and sending that to me? In other words, if I only have a public validation key, how do I know that it's a public key, from a trusted provider - unless I somehow validate either the key or it's origin?

Comment: Because the token signature is created using the private key, then using the public key, the receiver of the token can verify that the token was issued by the intended token provider. Typically, for example in .NET, the AddJwtBearer handler, will at startup download the public key from the trusted token provider (over HTTPS).   This happens over the back-channel. Also, the kid claim inside the token should also match the id of the public key downloaded.

Comment: It makes sense that it needs to validate the public key somewhere. But then, why put it in the token in the first place (even ignoring it's size).

Comment: It might be because the API that receives the token can't reach the service that issued the tokens (perhaps it is in an offline environment?). The other alternative is to provide the public key,  to the clients and APIs at startup. Besides the public-key, there are other "security" concepts in OpenID-Connect that complements the signature. For example, the receiver of the token should verify that the aud claims matches the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't get what prevents someone from using a fake key-pair to create a similar token.

Given the validations in [Self-Issued ID Token Validation](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#SelfIssuedValidation)  there is no feasible way for "someone" to sign a token which would have the same `sub` (JWT Subject). Of course they may sign a Token which would pass validations, but ONLY for a different subject. So IF you choose to accept Self-Issued ID Tokens, the guarantee you get is that you can re-identify the same Subject. That's kind of the whole point, Self-Issued OpenID providers are **personal** wallets, given the cryptography present in the flow you can be sure a given returned subject is the same one you encountered prior as long as `sub` is the same as before (or one that you know and have established trust with OOB).

Node.js code as a reference:

```js
import * as assert from "node:assert";
import * as jose from "jose";

let jwt;

const redirect_uri = "https://rp.example.com/siop/cb";
const nonce = "n-0S6_WzA2Mj";

{
  // this is unreachable by the party verifying
  const kp = await jose.generateKeyPair("ES256");
  const sub_jwk = await jose.exportJWK(kp.publicKey);

  jwt = await new jose.SignJWT({ sub_jwk, nonce })
    .setSubject(await jose.calculateJwkThumbprint(sub_jwk))
    .setIssuer("https://self-issued.me")
    .setAudience(redirect_uri)
    .setProtectedHeader({ alg: "ES256" })
    .setExpirationTime("5m")
    .setIssuedAt()
    .sign(kp.privateKey);
}

const verified = await jose.jwtVerify(
  jwt,
  async (protectedHeader, token) => {
    const { sub_jwk, sub } = JSON.parse(
      new TextDecoder().decode(jose.base64url.decode(token.payload))
    );
    assert.equal(sub === (await jose.calculateJwkThumbprint(sub_jwk)), true);

    const key = await jose.importJWK(sub_jwk, protectedHeader.alg);

    assert.equal(key.type, "public");

    return key;
  },
  {
    audience: redirect_uri,
    issuer: "https://self-issued.me",
  }
);

assert.equal(verified.payload.nonce, nonce);

console.log(verified);
```

Comment: But in this example, you assume that you have access to the public key from other sources, than just the token, right?

Comment: This example simply validates the Self Issued ID Token to be valid. Whether you trust the subject (pre existing knowledge) or just care about re-identifying the same user as you did previously is up to your policy and you can use the validated `verified.payload.sub` for that purpose.

Comment: Supporting this behaviour is optional **if** you want to support personal wallets for site logins. FWIW SIOP as linked is being further developed by a new spec targetting the more recent personal wallet developments. https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-self-issued-v2-1_0.html

Comment: And it is entirely the Relying Party's policy decision to support SIOP or not.